# Hyperspectral Imaging

Tags: spectroscopy, biophysics, biology, medical-physics, mass-spectrometry

Is it possible for a HSI camera to detect how long back a particular wound occured in the body?

Eg: There's a body for postmortems with some marks/wounds at some places, can a HSI camera help us in giving an estimate about how long back that wound would have occured?

Comment: I don't think so. Not from surface temperature, which is what a thermal infrared camera measures.

Comment: It seems unlikely, but could be worth investigating.  There are certainly chemical changes associated with time after death; and those might be detectable with high-resolution HSI.  However, there could be a lot of confounding factors like temperature, humidity, body-mass index, blood loss, etc., that would need to be figured in.

Comment: I think this is a question for Biology.SE, not Physics. It's biology that deals with how body tissues change over time.